# MySQL8.0 CHARACTERs and COLLATIONs are different between 2 databases

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

I have two RDS instances and two databases on each of them that have exactly the same name.
One of them is created from another originally, so they were completely the same scheme previously.

However, after upgrading MySQL5.7 to MySQL8.0, there has been different between them.
In detail, it's about CHARACTER and COLLATION of some columns.

For example, here are the sample of the parts of CREATE statements produced by Workbench.

In staging database:

```
`test_column` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8mb3_bin DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Bluh bluh...',
```

In production database:

```
`test_column` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8mb3_bin DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Bluh bluh...',
```

I guess it indicates that the production column has the "Default" CHARACTER and the staging one has the "Specified" CHARACTER.
Database level CHARACTER and COLLATION setting are not different.

I'd like to make the staging one be the same as the production one, what kind of query is to resolve this problem?

Comment: What does `show create table yourtablename` show?  No idea what workbench is choosing to do, better to go straight to the database for your info.  If they have the same collation, they are the same.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I've tried "show create table mytablename" but the result is the same as above. One of them has `CHARACTER SET utf8mb3` information whereas another has "nothing" about CHARACTER information. Is there any way to set "nothing" to CHARACTER to the staging column?

Comment: I resolved it by myself. Simply modify my column without character set. Thanks.

Comment: does the default character set for the table differ (last line of show create table)?

Comment: There's no difference. I have no idea about that "nothing set to character of a column" but I get that it can be fixed once I get rid of all settings from the column and then set what I want again.